# Alternative to forward declaration not working in namespace

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I've understood that as an alternative to forward declarations of classes you can use C-style identifiers/declarations like this:

```
//instead of
class Foo;

void func(Foo* foo);

//do

void func(class Foo* foo);
```

But I've got an issue in this case, only after changing the settings in my compiler (Visual Studio). I think it was set to permissive, or wasn't enforcing many of the conformance standards.

```
namespace Foo
{
    void func(class Bar* bar) {}
}

class Bar {};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo::func(&bar); // argument of type "Bar *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Foo::Bar *"    
// cannot convert argument 1 from 'Bar *' to 'Foo::Bar *'   

}
```

If Foo was a class then this would work fine. Is there not a way of doing this with a namespace?

Comment: Now put `class Bar {};` before `namespace Foo`...

Comment: You have two different classes, with the same name `Bar`. One in the globla namespace and other in the Foo namespace.

Comment: @KamilCuk If I put class Bar {} before the namespace it works. So this isn't possible because the class Bar that's in the function argument list is always treated as a different class Bar?

Comment: @Zebrafish - It's only ever treated as *one* class Bar. Doing it this way you are asking the compiler to implicitly forward decalre the class. And it will only put that implicit forward declaration into the nearest enclosing namespace.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica "And it will only put that implicit forward declaration into the nearest enclosing namespace", that's fine, so it's the equivalent of forward declaring class Bar; within that namespace, which is good enough to declare a function taking a pointer to Bar, but why then can't I call that function from anywhere? It seems as if it treats the forward declaration Bar in that namespace as another type, (it says can't convert to Foo::Bar)

Comment: Because it is another type. That's the point of namespaces. `Bar` in different namespaces are different classes. And you defined a  `Bar` in the global namespace, after forward declaring `Foo::Bar`.

Comment: Did you mean to define `Foo::Bar`?

Comment: @StoryTeller That's OK. I was just trying to use the class Bar in the argument list instead of at the top as a forward declaration. I understand now they're two types. I'm getting a error now from Visual Studio saying "a type cannot be introduced in a function parameter list". I can't recreate the error in a new project, but it's the case that the forward declaration works but not the class Bar in the argument list

Answer (score 1):

The Error was simple.
You called the class Bar then after that u declared it.
Here's the corrected Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  

class Bar {};
namespace Foo
{
    void func(Bar* bar) { cout << "Hello World!" << endl; }
}
//class Bar {};     A Functions/Class/Struct etc's prototype must be defined before its used/called in a function

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo::func(&bar); // argument of type "Bar *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Foo::Bar *"    
                     // cannot convert argument 1 from 'Bar *' to 'Foo::Bar *'

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    //-- My Special Touch
}
```

Whenever a function is called it looks above the function its called in if its prototype or definition is present or not.